# Can't get tomcat define a datasource

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

i placed this code inside META-INF (folder in the same depth of WEB-INF) / context.xml

```
<Context path="/checchin" docBase="webapps/checchin">
    <Resource name="jdbc/ChecchinDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root"
        password="redhat81" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chechin" />
</Context>
```

and then i place

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>mySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>java/ChecchinDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

inside web.xml

But i can't get work it! Tomcat doesn't display anything about a deployment of the datasource and then spring fails to reference DS. Is something missing? I've no experience with tomcat... but i follwed what's written in tomact guide.

Here the stack trace:

```
    Informazioni: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d3ff7a: defining beans [appConfig,multipartResolver,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#3,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#5,accessDeniedHandler,messageSource,concurrencyFilter,sas,sessionRegistry,authFilter,org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#1,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,passwordEncoder,userDetailsService,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#1,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
    ott 13, 2013 2:56:31 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    Grave: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#5' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#1' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/persistence-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ChecchinDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ChecchinDB].
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

...

    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ChecchinDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ChecchinDB].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
        at org.springframew

ork.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 110 more
```

Comment: make sure you copied the mysql driver into tomcat lib folder `<<CATALINA_BASE>>/lib`

Comment: but I don't see any problem with the data source, it seems it belongs to spring fw.

Comment: At the end of the unbelievably long error message is this: Name [ChecchinDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ChecchinDB]. This is just a guess but in one place it says java/ChhecchinDB and in another it says jdbc/ChecchinDB. Could this difference be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shoudn't `resource-ref.res-ref-name` and `Resource.name` be the same? You use "**java**/ChecchinDB" and "**jdbc**/ChecchinDB" as a identifier

Comment: I corrected the reference but i still can get this to work; this is the spring datasource conf:  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/ChecchinDB" />
 </bean>